# Query database then email posts from where user is subbed to

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

So I have a subscriptions table, here's the schema

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_to      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_subbed | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Pretty basic, here's an example row

```
+----+---------+--------+------------------------+
| id | user_id | sub_to | date_subbed            |
+----+---------+--------+------------------------+
| 23 |      13 |      2 | 08/19/2014 07:44:49 pm |
+----+---------+--------+------------------------+
```

All pretty basic stuff. So user `13` is essentially subbed to user `2`. So lets say that another user joins the site and another row is created with user `14` subs to user `5`.

And now user `2` and user `5` post a message on the site and it gets inserted into the database. I want the users who are subscribed *to* someone to get an email with the newest post.

```
//Get user subs
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscription");
$stmt->execute();

foreach ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $key) {
    print_r($key);
}
```

I've already tried a foreach loop but I couldn't see how it would work. So to sum things up I want to email the user when their is a new post. I'll be sending out an email every 24 hours so I don't kill the server. I want to make sure it's fully automated too. I know how to do the 24 hour time thing, but when I say automated I mean that it'll query and email by its self.  Any pointers or ideas?

Comment: You should store dates in the database using `date` or `datetime`, and not as a character.  If you *have* to store them as characters, then use the format YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.

Comment: Yes I am aware. I'm only using it for testing. But thanks :) @GordonLinoff

Comment: why would you knowingly do it wrong "but only for testing" ?!?!

Comment: Didn't I answer this a few hours ago? What happened to that question?

Comment: It's been a long day...  @Dagon

Comment: I felt like I needed to add more because nobody understood what I meant, so that's exactly what I did @Barmar

Comment: It would of ended up getting closed. Then don't..... @Barmar

Comment: This is an overly broad question that shows little original work. Quoting from the post "I've already tried a foreach loop but I couldn't see how it would work"... what is "it"? what does not work? Have you tried using a scheduler like cron or at? Are you familiar with the PHP `mail` command? What SQL queries have you tried beyond `SELECT * FROM subscriptions`? Is there any other code that you've tried? SO does not exist to give pointers or ideas, SO exists to give concrete answers to clear questions.

Comment: Please check the new set code and hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just use `ob_start()`, and loop through each user. Select the posts they're subscribed to. Then inside the loop email it to each user. I used this query

```
SELECT
    articles.*
    FROM
    articles
    INNER JOIN subscriptions ON articles.from_id = subscriptions.sub_to
    INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id
    WHERE
    users.email = :email
```

Comment: so what query did you use? In terms of deliverability, you probably want to call a single mail() from php, with the recipients fields including all users who are getting a mailing. use mail() as few times as possible if you're doing lots of mailings

Comment: I updated the query. And why should I try to use `mail()` as few times as possible? Too much power needed? @J-Dizzle

Comment: There are things called spam ratings and sender scores, and if you are not careful then your all your mail will end up in directly recipients spam folders. It will also decrease run time of your script when you do it with as few mail()s as possible

Comment: @J-Dizzle slightly off-topic, but I'm just curious : assuming I'd want to call `mail()` only once for 10 recipients can I get them all in the `TO:` while at the same time NOT have them see each others addresses? I know I could put them in `BCC:` which servers exactly this purpose, but that probably looks weird on the receiving end as `TO` an `CC` will be empty. Just wondering.

Comment: I'm running the following test to see what happens with the "TO:" headers: http://pastebin.com/FnDWqPwz ... I'm waiting on the mail server right now, but if you want to test it just replace the emails in $mailto with valid emails. I don't think it would be all that weird to send to recipients with the BCC: header.

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1ceb/9

I kindof tried to do what your saying with SQL fiddle, but in trying it out it seemed impossible with the current schema. In the link above I have many comments about how you should completely redesign your schema. The query is a pretty big headache and not scalable unless you set up a new schema.

Comment: Well what about the email part now? I'd have to loop through all the users and email them their content.....

Comment: Select the ones that the emails is going through, concatenate that into one comma separated list. Put that into the recipients field in [php's mail() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) You can do it!

Comment: I feel like I'm making this harder than it is. So I'm trying the SQL on my own computer, [this](http://pastebin.com/VBfJjXhH) is what it looks like and all I get is `Array()`, not sure why this happens, even though I have records....

Comment: Well it is a rather complicated issue, so you're actually over simplifying, I still think that if this is a real application it's not going to scale very well unless you [normalize the data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: @Idris is there anything else you were curious about? the php loop for doing the mailing itself?

Answer (score -1):

```
           $sql="select email id from subscription"; 
           $rs=mysql_query($sql); //resultset
           if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0) //checking whether anyone subscribed the user or not
           {
                 while($d=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
                 {
                     $sql1="select * from subscription where sub_to in ('".$d["user_id"]."')";
                     $rs1=mysql_query($sql1);

                     while($ds=mysql_fetch_array($rs1)
                     {

                         $to=$ds["email_id"];//assuming the field for email id
                         $subject="";
                         $msg="";  
                         @mail($to,$subject,$msg);
                     }

                 }

           }
```

Comment: I'm not doing specific users. I want to go through all the users and send emails to all of them who are subbed to something. And `mysql`.... Seriously?

Answer (score -2):

```
    $sql="select email id from subscription";
    $rs=mysql_query($sql); //resultset
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)>0) //checking whether anyone subscribed the user or not
    {
       while($d=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
       {               
            $sql1="select email id from subscription where sub_to in('".$d["user_id"]."')";
            $rs1=mysql_query($sql1);
            while($ds=mysql_fetch_array($rs1))
            {
                  $to=$ds["email_id"];//assuming the field for email id
                  $subject="";
                  $msg="";  
                  @mail($to,$subject,$msg);
            }//inner while end
       }//outer while end
    }
```